# Handlebars template not rendering as expected

Tags: backbone.js, handlebars.js

Here's the code that renders inside a Backbone view:

```
   var template = Handlebars.compile($('#some-hbs-template').html());
   var rendered = template({'hi':'sir','users':[{'username:':'denman','firstName': 'alex', 'lastName': 'mills'}]});
   this.$el.html(rendered);
```

the template looks like so:

```
<script id="some-hbs-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    hello:{{hi}}
    <table>
        <thead>
        <th>Username</th>
        <th>Real Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {{#users}}
            <tr>
                <td>{{username}}</td>
                <td>{{firstName}} {{lastName}}</td>
                <td>{{email}}</td>
            </tr>
        {{/users}}
        </tbody>
    </table>
</script>
```

the only thing that gets rendered to the page is the table headers:

> Username  Real Name   Email

I can't figure out why nothing else is showing up? "hello:" shows up but 'hi' is not rendering either.

Comment: You have stray colons in your JavaScript object keys, `'username:'` should be `'username'` and such.

Comment: good catch, but unfortunately that's not the problem either. 'users' is there, it should be passed, no idea what is going on. I always have the worst luck with templating.

Comment: I was able to get EJS working but now I am stuck with Handlebars. This should be easy.

Comment: Maybe providing a jsfiddle.net link to show us exactly what you're currently doing would help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [`each`](http://handlebarsjs.com/builtin_helpers.html#iteration) helper to loop over an array. `#users` isn't a built-in helper.

```
<script id="some-hbs-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <table>
        <thead>
        <th>Username</th>
        <th>Real Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {{#each users}} // NOTICE THIS...
            <tr>
                <td>{{username}}</td>
                <td>{{firstName}} {{lastName}}</td>
                <td>{{email}}</td>
            </tr>
        {{/each}} //...AND THIS.
        </tbody>
    </table>
</script>
```

You will also need to use this version of your render:

`var rendered = template({'users':[{'username':'denman','firstName': 'alex', 'lastName': 'mills'}]});`

so that users is defined in the data.

Comment: thank you, I stole an example from online and the example omitted the each

Comment: this is absolutely killing me, front-end development still blows major chunks

Comment: @AlexMills this seems to work just fine here http://jsfiddle.net/12ama699/1/ There must be something else wrong with your code.

Comment: thanks, nope this JSFiddle does not work in my Express server (I tried the exact code), my only guess is that it might be an issue with Express not rendering Handlebars templates correctly. I did succeed with EJS templates in the past, but only after quite a struggle.